# issue using IN clause with sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN
(SELECT  Column1 FROM Table2)
```

Actually there is no column named Column1 in the Table2.
So if we execute only the sub query

```
 SELECT  Column1 FROM Table2
```

it will throw the error -  Invalid column name 'Column1'.

But if I Execute the full query , I am not getting any error. It is returing the total row count in Table1.

So I would like to know the reason why this query it not giving any error in this case And the way the IN clause works in this scenario.

Comment: Show the data structure of `Table1` and `Table2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a subquery, you're allowed to access columns from the outer query. And that's what's happening here:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN
(SELECT  Column1 FROM Table2)
```

Could also be written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN
(SELECT Table1.Column1 FROM Table2)
```

Provided that there's at least one row in `Table2`, the subquery will always return the `Column1` value from `Table1`, and the `IN()` will be successful.

This is one reason I usually recommend using aliases:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Column1 IN
(SELECT t2.Column1 FROM Table2 t2)
```

will produce an error if there's no `Column1` in `Table2` - or, if you *do* reference `t1` inside the subquery, it's more obvious that it's deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

The count returned are the results from `Table1` not `Table2`. If you look at the execution plan you can see that it uses a `LEFT SEMI JOIN` for the query, therefore if it can't join on the columns I assume the following query will be executed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1
```

Which is why the query is still valid and returns the same output.